# Subtle difference in Two ALTER Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am comparing the structure of two SQL Server databases. In the first db I see:

```
alter table site add
  constraint DF__site__count_em default (0) for count_em;
```

and in the 2nd database I see:

```
alter table site add
  constraint DF__site__count_em default ((0)) for count_em;
```

Notice the 2nd set of parenthesis around the default value.

are these equivalent? Is there ever a reason to use a 2nd set of parenthesis?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you add one more set of parenthesis it won't throw any error unless you miss to close a parenthesis

Comment: Of course they are equivalent. Do you observes some difference?

Comment: No, I do not observe any differences. I just want to make sure there is not a subtle difference that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what Hamlet Hakobyan indicated there is no difference.